# "No objects or images found to bake to."

Tags: texturing, uv, normal-map

So basically, I have a building in which part of the walls are the same white plaster texture. I made those walls one object and made a single uv map from them. Now im trying to bake a diffuse and normal map for it with no luck. I have added a new image, named it diffuse and baked but always get the "No objects or images found to bake to." Any suggestions? I am really new to all this by the way. I thought possibly it could be the way my UV map is, with it all scaled up and the texture small, but that was the only way I could scale it to look right in my scene. Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ujT.png)

Comment: Update: I have tried fitting the UV map inside the white wall image. Baking still fails.

Comment: Are you baking with Cycles? You have to have a material with Image node inside (can be unplugged, just floating) with the image loaded into the node. The node should be selected.

Comment: @Jerryno Im using blender render. All I want to do Is bake diffuse so I can make a normal map from it in crazy bump or something. That way when I import to a game engine, everything is the right size. In the scene, the texture repeats seamlessly because the UV map is scaled up. Not sure how I can bake a map like that. or why Im getting the error thats preventing me from trying.